# Is there any way to ensure that your CNN model predicts outputs following certain thresholds?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a network which takes in an input image and outputs 37 values that are essentially the features. For e.g. the entire output class is a series of questions whose values are the percentage of people who agreed upon the said feature. 0.60 for `class1` and 0.4 for `class12`.

Now, there are some conditions such that the output of the model can't have one class that is higher than the other. E.g. `class1.1` must be higher than `class3.2` as it is a higher question in the decision tree. 
Is there any way we can implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly outputting *a, b* from your neural network you can output *a, a + ReLU(b)* which ensures the second output is higher than or equal to the first.